# How to extract account information from thunderbird?

Tags: windows, thunderbird, imap, pop3

I can extract all information related with any outlook account from windows registry on windows machine. Like Incoming and outgoing server, username , encrypted password and account type(POP or IMAP). All information which I can collect from windows registry is in hex.

**I want to extract same information for account which I have configured in thunderbird**.

Is there any way to do this in windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Information about Thunderbird account is stored in plain text file at user profile

```
%appdata%\thunderbird\profiles\%yourprofile%\prefs.js
```

Passwords are stored under `key3.db` and `signons.sqlite` at same location, but those are somewhat encrytped.

Comment: Thank you bro.. It is very help full...

is there any way to get ports define in outlook? because in windows registry I can get all account settings except port numbers for smtp, imap or POP accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Nirsoft's [MailPassView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/mailpv.html) will extract account details from most common mail clients, including port numbers.  Like all Nirsoft stuff it's a very useful little tool, although many anti-virus applications will detect it as 'Hack Tool' or 'Potentially Unwanted Program', for obvious reasons.